Error: secretOrPrivateKey is not valid key material - no answer found
Can anyone help me with the following error: Error: secretOrPrivateKey is not valid key material.
I'm creating an express API with node. I have a login route where a jsonwebtoken is created for the user if login is succesfull.
The webtoken is created the following way: const jToken = jwt.sign(process.env.SECRET_TOKEN, {expiresIn: "20m"});
SECRET_TOKEN is created in a .env file: SECRET_TOKEN=lalala
As far as I'm concerned, the syntax of the .env file is correct.
The code executes and a localhost website is created but when I try to use the /login route with POST http method I get the error. I use postman.
I have tried to solve it on my own, I have:

Made sure the syntax of the code is correct
require('dotenv').config(); is executed before process.env.SECRET_TOKEN
I have updated all the packages that I'm using


Please provide a [mre] of the issue in question. It's difficult to provide you with anything resembling helpful advice without it. See also [ask]
